# How do I loop thorough an array of objects but print only the first 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

Here is the code that I have that hits the API and appends all five to the li in the ul id="cards". How can I limit the results to the first two only?

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
success: function(data){
  var cards = data.results;
  console.log(cards);
  $.each(cards, function(i, card) {
    $("#cards").append('<li> ' + card.category + ' </li>');
  });
```

}
  });

Comment: within function use this condition `if (i < 2) {$("#cards").append('<li> ' + card.category + ' </li>');}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) the callback function accepts index and value: function( index, value ); so in your case i is the index.

This should work:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
success: function(data){
  var cards = data.results;
  console.log(cards);
  $.each(cards, function(i, card) {
    if(i <=  1)
        $("#cards").append('<li> ' + card.category + ' </li>');
    else
        return false; //THis is the correct way to break a jquery each loop
  });
```

Comment: How did I not think of that?? So obvious! Thanks!

Comment: I would put an else there to return and exit the loop otherwise it'll keep looping

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF` condition with in a `each` method.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
      var cards = data.results;
      console.log(cards);
      $.each(cards, function(i, card) {
    if(i<2){
        $("#cards").append('<li> ' + card.category + ' </li>');
    }
      });
}
     });
```

Comment: index starts at 0

Comment: ya thats my mistake

Answer (score 0):

No need for an each ... or any other loop

```
$("#cards").append('<li>' + cards[0].category + '</li><li>' + cards[1].category + '</li>');
```

Comment: Assuming the API always returns at least 2 cards.